# Setting isolation levels in IIS?

Tags: iis-7.5

In my **IIS** server I want to set the isolation levels, but I am unable to find  where and how to set this.

Please help me to set the `isolation` levels in IIS.

Comment: IIS 5 was the last version to support isolation levels.

Answer (score 2):

By default IIS7 isolates each site in its own application pool at creation time (via the IIS Manager MMC).

This would be analogous to setting the isolation level (High Isolation) in Windows 2000/IIS5. Windows 2003/IIS6 had a backwards compatibility mode to allow IIS6 to behave like IIS5 rather than use Application Pools.

So basically you don't really need to explicitly set the "isolation" level in IIS7 as it's the default (unless of course you're creating sites programmatically and in this case you need to be explicit).

Answer (score 0):

In IIS 7, Integrated mode and Classic mode are set at the application pool level...
Check this link for details:
"https://supportportal.fullcontrol.net/KB/a171/iis-70-application-pools.aspx"